# Satellites, weather-satellites and remote-sensing, why not earth-observation-satellite for the first two and keep the third for non-satellite Q's?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-synonyms, retagging

To the question [How can I relation aerosol particle size (2, 5 and 10 microns) with the aerosol index measurement of the Sentinel-5P (TROPOMI) data sets?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/22751/6031) I've added both

- [satellites](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satellites) **50** questions

> The satellites tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [weather-satellites](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather-satellites) **31** questions

> The weather-satellites tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

but looking at these questions there is substantial overlap if not complete interchangeability.

Since the word "satellite" can include natural satellites, why not use some "moderator magic" and create an `earth-observation-satellite` tag (similar to Space SE's [earth--observation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth-observation) tag) and replace both tags with it?

Note there is also

- [remote-sensing](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-sensing) **89** questions

> Questions about measurements which are taken from remote locations / are not taken in situ.

which has some overlap but is much broader.

Perhaps `earth-observation-satellite` questions should then have the remote-sensing tag removed, unless explicitly about things other than satellites.

The usage guidance for each could be updated to include guidance about the other as well.